# WSDL Import fails in BPEL using Developer Studio

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio

Hi I am working BPEL using WSO2 developer studio. I am trying to invoke a web service deployed in WSO2-AS using it's wsdl 1.1.

In the BPEL editor I added a partner link (using + button in palette)
In the properties window I click on Browse and then in the popup window I clicked on Add WSDL button. 
There I selected the URL radio button and pasted the wsdl 1.1 url of my axis service. But the service is not imported.

I tried with WSDL 2.0 url then also it failed.  ( I tried both Axis and Jax-ws )

Then I tried importing a wsdl url of a web service (jax-ws) deployed in tomcat using netbeans. It worked fine.

Could you please help me to understand this problem?

Thanks in advance
Sunil Binkam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2 BPS bpel package requires all artifacts to be in the same location. So the easiest method to do that is to just same the wsdl file into the bpel project folder from the browser and click refresh. Then you can import the wsdl from the developer studio.

Thanks
Nandika